# Change the text style of a ComboBox item in a dynamic ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox in my form displaying the list of available COM ports. Here is the code I wrote:

[XAML]

```
<Window x:Class="test1.MainWindow" x:Name="cbtest1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="40">
            <ComboBox x:Name="com_ports" ItemsSource="{Binding PortsList}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace test1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var ports = new List<string>(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames());
            var cb = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
            foreach (var x in ports)
            {
                cb.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = x });
                var p = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(x);
                if (p.IsOpen)
                {
                    // Bold that item in the combobox
                }
            }
            PortsList = cb;
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> PortsList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, as I have commented in the code, I want the ComboBox to display the open ports in **bold**. I have no idea what to do. I searched for a while on the SO and google, but had no luck. I appreciate if someone simply explains this to me -a WPF/C# noob.

Comment: You could set some property in the ComboBoxItem model, like IsOpen, to true. And then use a **[datatrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)** in xaml styles to change appearance.

Comment: @3615 As a noob, I really appreciate an answer. I have been googling for a while and now I beg for something to save me from all the suffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest change would be

```
        foreach (var x in ports)
        {
            var addMe = new ComboBoxItem { Content = x };
            cb.Add(addMe);
            var p = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(x);
            if (p.IsOpen)
            {
                addMe.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you all for positive feedback. Of course this is done without ViewModel (it could even work without DataContext and without Binding but just adding the ComBoxItems directly to the com_ports combo Items property. Next step could be to apply MVVM if you want and go on with a more complex solution... for the moment thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In WPF you apply changes to elements by overriding there display-template.

A good startingpoint to understand it is this little tutorial here:
[link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/)

Please note, that this approach seems kind of complex, but it is also very flexible and you can do various other things by using this.

**Im writing this without Visual Studio, so there could be some syntax errors**

For your specific example i would use the following model class so you can bind to some properties easier:

```
public class MyPortModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _displayName;
    private bool _isOpen;

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _displayName; }
        set
        {
            _displayName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
        }
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return _isOpen; }
        set
        {
            _isOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsOpen");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then change your code behind to the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var ports = new List<string>(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames());
    var cb = new ObservableCollection<MyPortModel>();
    foreach (var x in ports)
    {
        var p = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(x);
        cb.Add(new MyPortModel { DisplayName = x,IsOpen = p.IsOpen});
    }
    PortsList = cb;
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
public ObservableCollection<MyPortModel> PortsList { get; set; }
```

and use this template to display the items:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="com_ports"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PortsList}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <local:IsOpenBoldConverter x:Key="IsOpenConverter"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        FontWeight="{Binding Path=IsOpen, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsOpenConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

as you can see a converter is used to be able to decide if the item should be displayed bold or normal.
heres the code for the converter:

```
public class IsOpenBoldConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return ((bool) value) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
        }
        return FontWeights.Normal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the general way to go. But personally, I prefer the shorter solutions.